# How can I make my "banner" on my webpage hide, on mobile devices, but re appear on bigger devices?

Tags: html, css

I have created my first website for an oil change business. 1stopexpresslube.com On the front page I have a banner in blue with the business name, hours of operation, phone and address. I removed the banner on all the subsequent pages, because when viewing on a mobile device you couldn't tell that you had switched pages because all you could see was the banner and the menu buttons on the mobile page which do not change. A quick solution I came up with was leaving banner on the initial index.html page, and then all other pages I removed the banner. I then got the idea to see if I could change my site, so that on the 2nd, 3rd, 4th etc pages I could have the banner that is in blue ONLY appear on larger devices. So on phones the banner would not be there, as it is right now, but when I view on a desktop, those 2nd, 3rd, 4th pages etc all show a banner. I tried the opacity element so it would show 0, but it just made the banner disappear but still take space. I would like the space to collapse. I also tried visibility: collapse; and hidden; and they both seemed to do the same as opacity: 0; Is there a way to make the banner remove itself from the document flow on mobile devices, and then reappear and take up space on larger screens?

Comment: Go research _CSS Media Queries_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, you can use media queries in your CSS, which allows you set different styles for different size screens.

```
/* Large desktop */
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .banner{ width:123px; display:block; }
}

/* Portrait tablet to landscape and desktop */
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) {
    .banner{ display:none; }
}

/* Landscape phone to portrait tablet */
@media (max-width: 767px) { ... }

/* Landscape phones and down */
@media (max-width: 480px) { ... }
```

Comment: thanks. .banner {display: none; } helped. thanks a lot.